# I want to color a cell in a dynamically created table via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create an HTML table via Javascript. After that I need to be able to color some of the table's cells (td).

```
for( var i=0; i<rows;i++)
{
    indx=i+1;
    tbody += '<tr>';
    for( var j=0; j<cols;j++)
    {
        tbody += '<td>';
        if(counter<n){
            debugger;

            factor=is_Semi_Prime(indx);

            if(factor[0].toString().length==factor[1].toString().length&&factor[0]!=-1)
                tbody+="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+indx+":"+"<br>"+factor[0]+", "+factor[1];
            else
                tbody+="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+indx+":"+"<br>";//here i need to paint this cell in green
        }
        else
            tbody+="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";//and here in white 

            tbody += '</td>'

            indx+=rows;
    }

    tbody += '</tr>\n';

}

var tfooter = '</table>';
str+=(theader + tbody + tfooter);
res.html(str); 

}
```

This is the part of table creation and data

Comment: What basis do you want to show bg color? Add CSS class accordingly...

Comment: cant i add this in the string just the background-color of the cell?

Comment: sure like tbody += '<td  style="background-color:#ddd">'; or += '<td   bgcolor="#000">';

Comment: you can create an array and assign it on the loop....

Comment: I've run your Javascript code and it doesn't work. Could you provide a more decent kind? For example "if(counter<n)" you don't specify counter or n. And there are still some other issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do styling of some specific TDs in your table after it is created, then you can use below code to reach to your TD:

```
document.querySelector("table>tbody>tr+tr>td+td").style["background-color"] = 'green';
```

You might want to pre-build that string inside querySelector method. You can simply increase the number of TRs and TDs getting added. The above example code changes the background color to green for a TD at second column and second row.
Of course, you might need specificity defined for your particular table you want to refer.